# long vowel spelling rule

Tags: pronunciation-vs-spelling, spelling-pronunciations, pronunciation-respelling

A spelling rule is saying something like "add e to the end of a word to get a long vowel."  for example:-

the o in hop is short vowel, that is why it has no e at the end.
the o in hope is long vowel.

but I could not understand the need for the e at the end of "medicine".  Appreciate explaining that to me.

Comment: You will be disappointed if you think English spelling has some absolute rules.  For example, the spelling of "medicine" comes from the French.  I suppose some spelling reformers may ask you to spell it "medasin" or something, but they never catch on.

Comment: It's a great rule as a starting point for understanding spelling and pronunciation in English.  But it works best with one-syllable words.  And it is only a starting point.  There are many, many exceptions.  // There is a helpful site for English Language Learners, if you haven't visited it yet, I invite you to check it out: http://ell.stackexchange.com/